# source(..., chdir=TRUE) does not seem to change the directory

Tags: r, chdir

I'm pretty new to R and I'm trying to source a file which is again sourcing files. So I have a file, lets call it mother.R which contains a source call:

```
source ("grandmother.R")
```

mother.R and grandmother.R are in the same directory.

I would now like to source mother.R:

```
source ("C:/Users/whatever/R/mother.R", chdir=T)
```

My assumption was that the `chdir=T` would cause the source within the source to be looked for under `C:/Users/whatever/R/`, but it does not find grandmother.R when sourcing like this. Do I missunderstand `chdir`? Is there a way to do this without have to use absolute paths in mother.R?

Comment: It's unclear what you actually want to do, but I believe `chdir=T` only affects the working directory while the code in `mother.R` is being run, not afterwards.  But in general, there's no good reason to use `source` inside a function or script.  If you can explain what your goal is, we can suggest a more efficient approach.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm surprised you say there's never a good reason to use `source`. Is there a better way to split code into multiple files?

Comment: @Matthew  Why would you split code that runs together into separate files?  But maybe a better question is "what is in the OP's  files to begin with?" .  Normally you should build a *package* so that all desired functions are in the same Namespace.  Running code off macros (scripts) is poor practice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your understanding of how `source` works seems correct to me. But let's write an example so you can compare with your setup and maybe find where you went wrong.

Let the `/Users/me/test/mother.R` file contain the following:

```
print("I am the mother")
print(paste("The current dir is:", getwd()))
source("grandmother.R") # local path
```

and let the `/Users/me/test/grandmother.R` file contain the following:

```
print("I am the grandmother")
```

Where you start will help understand:

```
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/me"
```

This does not work:

```
> source("/Users/me/test/mother.R")
[1] "I am the mother"
[1] "The current dir is: /Users/me"
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'grandmother.R': No such file or directory
```

because R is looking for `grandmother.R` in the `getwd()` dir...

Instead,

```
> source("/Users/me/test/mother.R", chdir = TRUE)
[1] "I am the mother"
[1] "The current dir is: /Users/me/test"
[1] "I am the grandmother"
```

works because `source()` temporarily changes the current directory to `/Users/me/test/` where it can find `grandmother.R`.

When `source` gives you the handle back, you end up where you started, meaning the `chdir` is local to the `source` call like @CarlWitthoft pointed out.

```
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/me"
```

Comment: Thanks flodel for your help. Thanks to your simple example I found the reason it didn't work in my case. I made the mistake of using `source("grandmother.R")` inside a function in mother.R. Naturally the `chdir` does not apply if the source is not called until this funktion is called. I need to call the source outside of the definition of any functions.

Comment: It seems that it is not a great idea to source scripts in functions in general, as I just had to learn myself.